# SAS: Observations as group to variables - transpose

Tags: sas, grouping, transpose

I think that's an easy one but I can't get my head around it.

I have a variable called GROUP, then a date variable and a value variable:

```
GROUP  Date   Value
A    1-1-2010 1
A    2-1-2010 2
A    3-1-2010 3
A    4-1-2010 4
B    1-1-2010 5
B    2-1-2010 6
B    3-1-2010 7
B    4-1-2010 8
C    1-1-2010 9
C    2-1-2010 10
C    3-1-2010 11
C    4-1-2010 12
```

What I want now is

```
Date       A   B   C  
1-1-2010   1   5   9
2-1-2010   2   6   10
3-1-2010   3   7   11
4-1-2010   4   8   12
```

I tried Proc transpose but it doesn't let me do it as group has more than one reoccurring observation.

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with `proc sql` -- if you know all the groups in advance:

```
proc sql;
    select date,
           max(case when group = 'A' then value end) as A,
           max(case when group = 'B' then value end) as B,
           max(case when group = 'C' then value end) as C
    from t
    group by date;
```

Comment: Why would you ever do it this way?  You have to know the groups in advance? Why not just use TRANSPOSE?  It handles this easily.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PROC TRANSPOSE`, you just have to sort things appropriately:

```
proc sort data=have out=temp;
by date group;
run;
```

then Transpose

```
proc transpose data=temp out=want;
by date;
id group;
var value;
run;
```